# How to insert data in the enum field?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-migrations

I've an `enum` field in my migration. The code is here:

```
 Schema::create('clients', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('preview_img');
        $table->enum('platform', ['android', 'ios']);
        $table->integer('sort')->default(0)->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

I'm trying to insert the following data in the enum:
[image]

I've the `protected $fillable = ['platform'];` in the `Client` model. 
But as the result I see the following:
[image]

Where is my mistake? 
I've tried this variant:

```
 $platform = '';
    foreach ($request->platform as $p) {
        $platform .= $p . ',';
    }
    $platform = rtrim($platform, ',');
    $client->platform = $platform;
```

But it does not work too.

Comment: You need to pass the only string 'android' or 'ios' in the `$request->platform` field. Can you `dd` the request object and check the value of the `$request->platform` field that you're getting.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it just now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are receiving a array on your `$request->platform` . Make sure you send just one option to your controller, this way:

In your **view**:

```
<select name='platform'>
  <option value="android">Android</option>
  <option value="ios">Ios</option>
</select>
```

In your **controller**:

```
$client->platform = $request->platform
```

If this don't work, please put this on your code `dd($request->platform)` and then show us

Comment: In my question I've a picture with the screen of xdebug session. It shows well what I have in the `$request->platform` https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbXyV.png

Comment: Well, this is strange, try this: ```$request->platform[0]``` im not sure why laravel recognize 'Android' as a array, but this should do the work.

Comment: Using `$request->platform[0]` might not be the best solution as it might always give Android option. It would be helpful if you add the view code that sends the request and `dd($request->platform)`.